# How can I read a text file from the internet with Java?

Tags: java, stream

I want to read the second line of the text at this URL: "http://vuln2014.picoctf.com:51818/" (this is a capture-the-flag competition but only asking for flags or direction to flags breaks the competition rules).  I am attempting to open an input stream from the URL but I get an Invalid HTTP Response exception.  Any help is appreciated, and I recognize that my error is likely quite foolish.

Code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://vuln2014.picoctf.com:51818");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = con.getInputStream()
```

The error occurs at the third line.
java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1342) at name.main(name.java:41)

curl happily gets the text from the page, and it is perfectly accessible from a web browser.

Comment: What does the stacktrace say?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this very same question not 2 hours ago?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : Same question was asked, except there was no code with it (originally)

Comment: stack trace > java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1342) at name.main(name.java:41)

Comment: @JohnDrake: since SO doesn't allow PMs, and you didn't leave any contact info on you profile, I'd just msg you here. I'd like to know if you've found the solution to your old/previous post http://quabr.com/28218639/find-expected-size-of-largest-weakly-connected-component; I'm facing the same problem, and don't know how to go about solving it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://vuln2014.picoctf.com:51818");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
```

You are entering into a contract that says that this URL uses the `http` protocol. When you call `openConnection` it expects to get `http` responses because you used `http://` in the URL as the protocol. The [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection()) says:

> If for the URL's protocol (such as HTTP or JAR), there exists a public, specialized URLConnection subclass belonging to one of the following packages or one of their subpackages: java.lang, java.io, java.util, java.net, the connection returned will be of that subclass. **For example, for HTTP an HttpURLConnection will be returned**, and for JAR a JarURLConnection will be returned.

The server you are connecting to just returns a couple lines of data. I retrieved them with the command `nc vuln2014.picoctf.com 51818`. There is no `http` response code *like* `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`:

> Welcome to the Daedalus Corp Spies RSA Key Generation Service. The public modulus you should use to send your updates is below. Remember to use exponent 65537.
>   b4ab920c4772c5247e7d89ec7570af7295f92e3b584fc1a1a5624d19ca07cd72ab4ab9c8ec58a63c09f382aa319fa5a714a46ffafcb6529026bbc058fc49fb1c29ae9f414db4aa609a5cab6ff5c7b4c4cfc7c18844f048e3899934999510b2fe25fcf8c572514dd2e14c6e19c4668d9ad82fe647cf9e700dcf6dc23496be30bb

In this case I would use `java.net.Socket` to establish a connection and then read the lines. This is a simplistic approach that assumes there are 2 lines of data:

```
Socket theSocket;
try {
    theSocket = new Socket("vuln2014.picoctf.com", 51818);
    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(theSocket.getInputStream()));

    String strGreet = inFile.readLine();
    String strData = inFile.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As for why curl and browsers may render it properly? They are likely more lenient about the data they read and will just dump what is read from the port even if it doesn't conform to the specified protocol (like `http`)

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I am a fool, as I suspected.

Comment: @JohnDrake You aren't a fool, it's not painfully obvious from the error what the issue is.